# Parse text from multiple file types

Tags: java, android, text

I am currently searching the sd card for any file types *.csv* and *.txt*. I am displaying the lines of these files as a toast. I'd like to now display only the lines that contain defined keywords. It seems to me that I should use the [RuleBasedCollator](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html) but I am not sure about how to implement it.

Is that the correct way I should be doing this or is there another, better solution?

Thanks

Code (I've commented on the second `if`, where my question is):

```
    private void conductScan() {

    File[] file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();  


    for (File f : file)
    {
       if (f.isFile() && f.getPath().endsWith(".xml") || f.getPath().endsWith(".txt")) {
           StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
           try {
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
               String line;
               while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                   text.append(line);
                   text.append('\n');
                   if (line ) {  //here I want to define if line contains "test" then show the toast"
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),line,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       } else {
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No keyewords found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       }
                   }
               }
           catch (IOException e) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error reading file!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
               String [] mStrings=text.toString().split("\n");
       }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if the line contains a substring you could use the:

[`public boolean contains(CharSequence s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

of the `String` class.

Not sure if that was the problem. The problem with this would be, that your loop will iterate through the lines really fast, and you won't be able to see the messages.

You could print those lines to the `Log` or into another text file to analize it later.

**EDIT:**

You could change this part:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
{
    //be careful! with this, you will add all the lines of
    //the currently processed file to a locally created 
    //StringBuilder object. Is this really what you want?
    text.append(line);
    text.append('\n');

    //here if line contains "test" you can do whatever you want with it.
    if (line.contains("test")) 
    {
        //do something with it
    }
    else
    {
        //no "test" keyword in the current line
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense..but it appears that android doesn't have the [boolean](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html) available to it. Can you confirm?

Comment: Can you please explain that last question? I don't really understand. Meanwhile i add the contains part to the answer.

Comment: Perfect thanks. Also I know as it stands this will cause memory crashes but this is the first outline of a program. Thanks!

Comment: You are wellcome! I'm happy to help where i can. :)